# Deleting columns from a file with awk or from command line on linux

Tags: awk

How can I delete some columns from a tab separated fields file with `awk`?

```
c1 c2 c3 ..... c60
```

For example, delete columns *between* 3 and 29 .

Comment: This answer on stackoverflow may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626274/awk-print-all-other-columns-but-not-1-2-and-3

Answer (score 45):

This is what the `cut` command is for:

```
cut -f1,2,30- inputfile
```

The default is tab. You can change that with the `-d` switch.

Comment: I had to remove the last `-` in order to make it work in Ubuntu. If I leave it, `cut` would print all the columns. Anyone had this problem too?

Comment: It should print columns one, two and thirty to the last one (60 in the question). If it doesn't that's a bug in Ubuntu!

Comment: Aaaah, ok. I made a mistake. My bad.

Comment: how to remove a specific column, for example the 3rd?

Comment: @becko Exactly the same way as removing a range of columns. What exactly are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I had trouble understanding your answer first, but now I realize that the argument to `cut` is the column numbers that you *keep* (I thought it was what you cut away). Thanks anyway

Comment: @user1436187 What does that mean? Which version of `cut` were you using? What was the problem that seemed to occur, and at what number of columns did it manifest?

Comment: @becko There's a common extension for that, `--complement`, which does what it says with the input field numbers, e.g.: `cut --complement -f3`.

Comment: How about 

`cut -f 3-29 --complement inputfile`

Its more intuitive and humane, since it mentions exactly what is to be removed, rather than tell what should be left post processing.

Comment: @kvaibhav Yes, that's what @underscore_d was suggesting. My guess is that `--complement` is a GNU extension. It's not present on the BSD version on my Mac for example.

Answer (score 13):

You can loop over all columns and filter out the ones you don't want:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (i<3 || i>29) printf $i " "; print""}' input.txt
```

where the `NF` gives you the total number of fields in a record.
For each column that meets the condition we print the column followed by a space `" "`.

---

EDIT: updated after remark from johnny:

```
awk -F 'FS' 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{for (i=1; i<=NF-1; i++) if(i<3 || i>5) {printf $i FS};{print $NF}}' input.txt
```

this is improved in 2 ways:

- keeps the original separators
- does not append a separator at the end

Comment: Shouldn't you print a tab (\t) instead of a space. He wants to remove fields, perhaps not remove tabs at the same time (if I understand you correctly).

Comment: @johnny: you are right. I updated the code so it should consider the separator correctly.

Comment: Lets assume based on your edited answer that we want to delete column number 2,5,7,8,23,45,67,254,554,488. What would be condition for this ? I have file with almost 4000 columns. @oliver

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(z=3;z<=15;z++)$z="";$0=$0;$1=$1}1'
```

Input

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c14 c15 c16 c17 c18 c19 c20 c21
```

Output

```
c1 c2 c16 c17 c18 c19 c20 c21
```

Comment: This doesn't delete columns. It blanks them and reprints... with OP's specified `O*FS` of `\t` replaced by a single space, which they didn't ask for. The _apparent_ deletion is coincidental and needs `FS` and `OFS` to be the default `\s+`. A pretty useless separator and incompatible with OP's `\t`, unless their file coincidentally can't have empty fields, as it'd squash them into jagged rows. Any other separator, e.g. OP's `\t`, gives output that still has the unwanted columns, but now empty. And `$0 = $0` is redundant and may be wasteful. The documented method to rebuild a record is `$1 = $1`

Answer (score 0):

Perl 'splice' solution which does not add leading or trailing whitespace:

```
perl -lane 'splice @F,3,27; print join " ",@F' file
```

Produces output:

```
c1 c2 c30 c31
```