# tail -f into grep into cut not working properly

Tags: bash, shell, grep, tail, cut

i'm trying to build a shell script to monitor some log files.
I'm using a command like this:

```
tail -f /var/somelog | grep --line-buffered " some test and p l a c e h o l d e r" | cut -f 3,4,14 -d " "
```

the log file is like:

```
some test and p l a c e h o l d e r 3
some test and p l a c e h o l d e r 4
some test and p l a c e h o l d e r 5
some test and p l a c e h o l d e r 6
```

and so on..
My issue is that the output of the command does not display the last line

```
some test and p l a c e h o l d e r 6
```

until line

```
some test and p l a c e h o l d e r 7
```

is added to the log.

I hope I made clear my issue.  Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe the log lines are not being ended with a line feed, but started with one instead? In this case line 6 would not really be complete until line 7 starts and provides that line feed. If you look at the log file, showing all characters, do you see a line feed at the end of the final line?

Comment: Look for a trailing new-line ("\n") using `od -c /var/somelog`.

Comment: Do you see the same output with just `tail -f` ? If that is the case then @David has pointed out it correctly.

Comment: I'm not al work at the moment, but if I run tail -f i can see the full log. I will try your solutions this evening and keep you posted :)

Comment: my guess is that you will see the full output (including the last line) with `tail -f`, and even with `tail -f | grep --line-buffered "pattern"`, but you will lose the last line once you introduce cut into the pipeline.

Comment: @nullrevolution you made the point.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

the problem is almost certainly related to how grep and cut buffer their output.  here's a hack that should get you around the problem, though i'm sure there are prettier ways to do it:

```
tail -f /var/somelog | while read line; do echo "$line" | grep "some test and p l a c e h o l d e r" | cut -f 3,4,14 -d " "; done
```

(don't forget the `; done` at the end of the command)

alternatively, because `gawk` doesn't buffer it's output, you could use it in place of `cut` to avoid the cumbersome while loop:

```
tail -f log | grep --line-buffered "some test and p l a c e h o l d e r" | gawk '{print $3,$4,$14}'
```

check out http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/ for more info on buffering problems.

Comment: It's also quite probable that whatever is writing to `/var/somelog` is buffering, so `tail` may not even see changes until it overflows a buffer or flushes its output some other way...

Comment: I have tried the first solution and is working. Thank you for your help!

Comment: glad to help.  don't forget that the best way to say thanks around here is to accept/upvote helpful answers! :)

Comment: oh man I can't believe it but cut appears to buffer its output, whereas grep et al don't.  Oh man that feels lame...