# delete a column with awk or sed

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file with three columns. I would like to delete the 3rd column(in-place editing). How can I do this with awk or sed?

```
123   abc  22.3
453   abg  56.7
1236  hjg  2.3
```

Desired output

```
123  abc
453  abg
1236 hjg
```

Comment: [For deleting two columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222121/how-to-remove-a-column-or-multiple-columns-from-file-using-shell-command)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -r 's/\S+//3' file
```

If you want to delete the white space before the 3rd field:

```
sed -i -r 's/(\s+)?\S+//3' file
```

Comment: @potong, is `\S` means _all characters that are not a space_ ? Where it is documented ?

Comment: What's `-r` do? My sed doesn't have it.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek `-r` is the GNU sed-specific option to enable EREs (google that). If you use `-E` instead of `-r` it'll work in GNU sed plus some other seds.

Comment: @GillesQuenot Yes, exactly. You can see it documented in the GNU manual in the section on [regular expression extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/regexp-extensions.html#regexp-extensions).

Comment: this only works for the first row for my GNU sed

Comment: doesn't work for tab delimited! see comment for awk above

Answer (score 74):

try this short thing:

```
awk '!($3="")' file
```

Comment: This doesn't actually delete the given column; it sets it to the empty string, but you still get an extra `FS` in your output.  This may or not be important, depending on what you're doing with the transformed data.

Comment: try this to save the generate output to a newfile. awk '!($3="")' file > newfile

Comment: @A.Danischewski this is not good way to go, what happens if the awk script has error? you lost your file. take this `awk '..' file > tmp &&  mv tmp file`

Comment: @A.Danischewski there are other circumstances that can affect: what if the file system has problems of space?

Comment: That will also recompile the current record replacing all white space between fields with single blank characters and removing any leading and/or trailing white space. It will not produce the OPs desired output given his posted input. To do that you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/38145415/1745001.

Comment: You can use `awk '!($3="")' | column -t` to get the columns white space back back

Comment: This doesn't delete anything for me. It just creates a bunch of empty columns. In some sense, it does the opposite of what is desired.

Answer (score 43):

With GNU awk for inplace editing, `\s/\S`, and [`gensub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to delete

1) the FIRST field:

```
awk -i inplace '{sub(/^\S+\s*/,"")}1' file
```

or

```
awk -i inplace '{$0=gensub(/^\S+\s*/,"",1)}1' file
```

2) the LAST field:

```
awk -i inplace '{sub(/\s*\S+$/,"")}1' file
```

or

```
awk -i inplace '{$0=gensub(/\s*\S+$/,"",1)}1' file
```

3) the N<sup>th</sup> field where N=3:

```
awk -i inplace '{$0=gensub(/\s*\S+/,"",3)}1' file
```

Without GNU awk you need a `match()`+`substr()` combo or multiple `sub()`s + vars to remove a middle field. See also [Print all but the first three columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18819899/1745001).

Comment: Note: on Ubuntu Trusty GNU Awk  4.0.1 doesn't have the `awk` inplace extension enabled by default.

Comment: i think you mean `/\s+\S+/` with an s`+` and not `/\s*\S+/`

Comment: @BrianWiley no because then it wouldn't work for the first field if there were no preceding spaces.

Answer (score 19):

Try using cut... its fast and easy

First you have repeated spaces, you can squeeze those down to a single space between columns if thats what you want with `tr -s ' '`

If each column already has just one delimiter between it, you can use `cut -d ' ' -f-2` to print fields (columns) <= 2.

for example if your data is in a file input.txt you can do one of the following:

```
cat input.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f-2
```

Or if you better reason about this problem by removing the 3rd column you can write the following

```
cat input.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' --complement -f3
```

cut is pretty powerful, you can also extract ranges of bytes, or characters, in addition to columns

excerpt from the man page on the syntax of how to specify the list range

```
Each LIST is made up of one range, or many ranges separated by commas.
Selected input is written in the same order that it is read, and is
written exactly once. Each range is one of:

  N     N'th byte, character or field, counted from 1
  N-    from N'th byte, character or field, to end of line
  N-M   from N'th to M'th (included) byte, character or field
  -M    from first to M'th (included) byte, character or field
```

so you also could have said you want specific columns 1 and 2 with...

```
cat input.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f1,2
```

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to what has been asked, but it sure is the best answer!

Comment: agreed, the rest of the answers deal with white space which will not work if you have spaces in a column for a file that is tab delimited.  this will work for tab delimited `cut -f1-241,243-267,269-278 -d$'\t'` which would remove columns 242 and 268.

Comment: This is the actual correct way to do it. It can also easily delete multiple columns simultaneously, which the sed solution is not able to do.

Answer (score 18):

It seems you could simply go with

```
awk '{print $1 " " $2}' file
```

This prints the two first fields of each line in your input file, separated with a space.

Comment: This assumes only 3 columns. You'll otherwise need a loop: `awk '{printf $1 OFS $2; for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) printf OFS $i; printf ORS}' file` (OFS defaults to a space and ORS defaults to a newline).

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
awk '$3="";1' file.txt > new_file && mv new_file file.txt
```

or

```
awk '{$3="";print}' file.txt > new_file && mv new_file file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk '{$3=""; print $0}'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're open to a Perl solution...

```
perl -ane 'print "$F[0] $F[1]\n"' file
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print every line
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the @F array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace
- `-e` execute the following perl code