# Split a sentence using space in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

How can I split a sentence using space, and print from second word onwards?

For example, if my sentence is `Hello World Good Morning`, then I want to print like:

```
World
Good
Morning
```

Comment: Expected output is word + new line + word ... ? Or space separated?

Comment: Why you posted the expected output like this? All the wonderful answers here target the above expected output only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `cut`:

```
$ echo "Hello World Good Morning" | cut -d' ' -f2-
World Good Morning
```

This tells `cut` to "cut" (surprisingly) based on `d`elimiter space and print from 2nd field up to the end.

---

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "Hello World Good Morning" | sed 's/^[^ ]* //'
World Good Morning
```

This gets, from the beginning of the line (`^`), a block of characters not containing a space (`[^ ]*`) and then a space and replaces it with empty content. This way, the first word is deleted.

---

With pure `bash`:

```
$ while IFS=" " read -r _ b; do echo "$b"; done <<< "Hello World Good Morning"
World Good Morning
```

This sets the field separator to the space and reads the first block in a dummy variable `_` and the rest in the variable `$b`. Then, it prints `$b`.

---

Also in `awk`, using this [Ed Morton's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18819899/1983854):

```
$ echo 'Hello World Good Morning' | awk '{sub(/([^ ]+ +){1}/,"")}1'
World Good Morning
```

This replaces 1 block of `not space characters` + block of `spaces` with an empty string.

Comment: Unsure if it was a typo on OP's part, but his output has a lower case w also his output has a newline after every word

Comment: Hi, both these worked great. Could you tell what is happening in `sed 's/^[^ ]* //'`

Comment: @UvaisIbrahim sure! See my update, I was writing it.

Comment: Oh @jaypal you are everywhere :D

Answer (score 5):

You can change the record separator to a space in awk and print from the second record onwards:

```
$ awk 'NR>1' RS=' ' <<<"Hello World Good Morning"
World
Good
Morning
```

As pointed out in the comments, there is also an extra blank line at the end of the output. This comes from the newline at the end of the input. If you are using GNU awk, it can be suppressed by setting the record separator to the `[[:space:]]` character class:

```
$ awk 'NR>1' RS='[[:space:]]' <<<"Hello World Good Morning"
```

Alternatively, as suggested by [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui), you can use `printf` instead of `echo` to pass the variable to awk:

```
printf '%s' 'Hello World Good Morning' | awk 'NR>1' RS=' '
```

Comment: Why it displays a blank line at the last?

Comment: Because the input contains a newline at the end and `print` also adds a newline.

Comment: Or you can also use `printf "Hello World Good Morning" | awk 'NR>1' RS=' '`.

Comment: @glenn I was about to mention that, I've edited now.

Comment: @fedorqui also a good suggestion, although I think that it's a good idea to use a format specifier in general. I've edited to include it, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the split+glob operator:

```
sentence="Hello World Good Morning"
set -f # disable the glob part
IFS=" " # split on space characters:
set  -- $sentence # apply the split+glob operator
                  # (leaving a variable expansion unquoted)
```

Now `$1` contains `Hello`... `$4` contains `Morning`.

```
shift 1 # (or just "shift") shifts the positional parameters by 1
printf '%s\n' "$@" # print them
```

Note that it splits on *sequences* of space character and ignores the leading and trailing ones.

The above works in any Bourne-like or POSIX shell except `zsh`, not just `bash`. With `zsh`, there's no implicit split+glob operator upon variable expansion unless in sh emulation. There is an explicit split `$=var` and explicit glob `$~var` operator. So in `zsh`:

```
sentence="Hello World Good Morning"
IFS=" "
set -- $=sentence
shift
printf '%s\n' "$@"
```

Or:

```
words=($=sentence)
printf '%s\n' $words[2,-1]
```

`zsh` also has variable expansion flags including a `s` one to split on a given string, and a more consistent way to nest variable expansions than in other shells, so:

```
$ printf '%s\n' ${${(s: :)sentence}[2,-1]}
World
Good
Morning
```

Comment: Stephane, did you mean: () { :;};printf ? ;)

Comment: Disabling globbing is a good idea. Mr. Shellshock, because of you we had a lot of work ;) Who invented the name shellshock?

Comment: `Mr.Shellshock`, apt name.

Answer (score 2):

A bash-specific example:

```
$ read -ra words <<< "Hello World Good Morning" && printf "%s\n" "${words[@]:1}"
World
Good
Morning
```

Comment: That assumes the _sentence_ doesn't contain newline characters and that IFS is either unset or contains space (by default or when unset, that will also split on tab). Replace `read -a` with `read -A` for it to work in ksh93 or zsh. `<<<` comes from `zsh`. `${words[@]:1}` comes from ksh93.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print on separate lines, you can use `tr`:

```
echo "Hello World Good Morning"|tr ' ' '\n'
```

To start printing from the 2nd word:

```
echo "Hello World Good Morning"|tr ' ' '\n'|tail -n+2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ more good
Hello World Good Morning

$ perl -p -e 's:Hello W:w:g;s: :\n:g' good 
world
Good
Morning

perl -p -e # Inline edit

's:Hello W:w:g #look for Hello followed by a space and the letter W, replace it with w

;s: :\n:g' # After you replace it, find any spaces and replace with a newline
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible through grep only, if your grep supports `-P` option.

```
grep -oP '(?:^\S+|(?<!^)\G)\h*\K\S+'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'Hello World Good Morning' | grep -oP '(?:^\S+|(?<!^)\G)\h*\K\S+'
World
Good
Morning
$ echo 'Hello World Good' | grep -oP '(?:^\S+|(?<!^)\G)\h*\K\S+'
World
Good
$ echo 'Hello World' | grep -oP '(?:^\S+|(?<!^)\G)\h*\K\S+'
World
```