# using awk or sed to print all columns from the n-th to the last

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, gawk

This is NOT a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961635). 
All previous questions/solutions posted on stackoverflow have got the same issue: additional spaces get replaced into a single space.

Example (1.txt)

```
filename Nospaces
filename One space
filename Two  spaces
filename Three   spaces
```

Result:

```
awk '{$1="";$0=$0;$1=$1}1' 1.txt
One space
Two spaces
Three spaces

awk '{$1=""; print substr($0,2)}' 1.txt
One space
Two spaces
Three spaces
```

Comment: @hek2mgl This is NOT a duplicate of another question. All previous questions/solutions posted on stackoverflow have got the same issue: additional spaces get replaced into a single space.

Comment: not all of them have that issue. See the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/29514679/1745001 for example.

Comment: Hang on - that was YOUR question! You accepted the right answer almost exactly a year ago and now you're back asking the same question again. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve whitespace in awk, you'll have to use regular expression substitutions or use substrings. As soon as you start modifying individual fields, awk has to recalculate $0 using the defined (or implicit) OFS.

Referencing Tom's sed answer:

```
awk '{sub(/^([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){1}/, "", $0); print}' 1.txt
```

Comment: this code doesnt work

Comment: It's fine with GNU awk. What awk are you using?

Comment: With that old version, use `gawk --re-interval '...'`

Comment: yup, works. but shorter, no subs needed already posted as an answer

Comment: one issue, if one of th elines contains less columns than the defined n-th column, it gets printed. fix: awk '{for(i=0;i<[column_id];i++)sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/,"")}1' 

Just wondering how does :space: differ from :blank: in this case

Comment: "space"  includes "vertical"  whitespace like newline.

Answer (score 2):

If you define a field as any number of *non-space* characters followed by any number of *space* characters, then you can remove the first `N` like this:

```
$ sed -E 's/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*){1}//' file
Nospaces
One space
Two  spaces
Three   spaces
```

Change `{1}` to `{N}`, where `N` is the number of fields to remove. If you only want to remove 1 field from the start, then you can remove the `{1}` entirely (as well as the parentheses which are used to create a group):

```
sed -E 's/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*//' file
```

Some versions of sed (e.g. GNU sed) allow you to use the shorthand:

```
sed -E 's/(\S+\s*){1}//' file
```

If there may be some white space at the start of the line, you can add a `\s*` (or `[[:space:]]*`) to the start of the pattern, outside of the group:

```
sed -E 's/\s*(\S+\s*){1}//' file
```

The problem with using awk is that whenever you touch any of the fields on given record, the entire record is reformatted, causing each field to be separated by `OFS` (the Output Field Separator), which is a single space by default. You could use awk with `sub` if you wanted but since this is a simple substitution, sed is the right tool for the job.

Comment: this doesnt work for the n-th column (2nd or 3rd)

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a very clear description of the problem. Anyway, I changed it slightly (use a `*` instead of a `+`). I guess that it should do what you expect now.

Answer (score 2):

Specify `IFS` with `-F` option to avoid omitting multiple space by `awk`

```
awk -F "[ ]" '{$1="";$0=$0;$1=$1}1' 1.txt
awk -F "[ ]" '{$1=""; print substr($0,2)}' 1.txt
```

Comment: works great. just wondering what are the caveats

Comment: Hmm now the problem is if I want to start fro mthe second column by using $1=$2=""

Comment: This works for even for nth column.

Comment: no it doesnt as there are multiple spaces in later columns

Comment: Edit your question to show the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' -f2- a.txt
```

prints all columns from the second to the last and preserves whitespace.

Comment: please read the question first

Comment: @meso_2600 Uh sorry, I tough you mean rows. I would use `cut`. Updated the answer.

Comment: and again. please read the question, it is awk or sed ;)

Comment: I read it. However, `cut` is obviously the right tool for the job. Usually asking something like "do this with tool A or B" is frowned upon because you already suggesting a probably wrong solution in the question. Why are you forced to use `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: cat encounters issues when the IFS consists of variable number of spaces, while awk handles this properly. This is why I have mentioned n-th column in the question. cut has problems as soon as I wnat to print 2nd->last column

Comment: @meso_2600  I cannot reproduce that. The example above shows how to print the 2nd to last column. If your "real" problem differs from the one described in the question, how should I give the right answer then?

Answer (score -1):

Working code in awk, no leading space, supporting multiple space in the columns and printing from the n-th column:

```
awk '{ print substr($0, index($0,$column_id)) }' 1.txt
```

Comment: this is just childish downvoting proper answer :)

Comment: Good answer. Potential downfall: same content in two different columns.

Comment: please share example as I can't reproduce such issue

Comment: ok i can see the issue. thanks. your answer is correct

Comment: For others: `echo foo bar baz bar | awk -v column_id=4 '{print substr($0, index($0,$column_id))}'` will print too many columns

Comment: You should delete this before it accumulates more downvotes.

Comment: Here is a `sed` way: `FIELD=2 && sed "s/^\([^ ]*\([ ]*\)\)\{${FIELD}\}/\2/;s/ //" s.txt`