# if $column_A="" equals to delete $column_A in awk?

Tags: awk

I wish to delete one column of my data in awk but what I found is using command like $column_A="". Is column_A really deleted in this way?

For example, I wish to delete the second column and I found a solution: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}!($2="")'` which print the result like: `$1^0^0$3`. It seems that it is the **content of** the second column is deleted but the second column.

Comment: make an example pls.

Comment: `echo 1 2 3 | awk '{$1=$2="";}1'` will output 3

Comment: You will probably remove the content. For a full solution, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18819899/1983854) in "Print all but the first three columns".

Comment: If you just want to remove a column, `cut` is the tool of choice. I've posted [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33830756/171318).

Answer (score 2):

after reading dev-null's comment, I got idea what are you asking...

My answer is: it depends on how do you define "a column is deleted".

see this example:

```
kent$  echo "foo,bar,blah"|awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$2="";print}'
foo,,blah

kent$  echo "foo,bar,blah"|awk -F, -v OFS="," '{print $1,$3}'
foo,blah
```

You see the difference? If you set the `$x=""` The column is still there, but it becomes an empty string. So the `FS` before and after stay. If this is what you wanted, it is fine. Otherwise just skip outputing the target column, like the 2nd example shows.

Comment: Yes, the second example is just what I want but the problem is there may be too many columns to remain while some other columns to be deleted. For example, there are total 50 columns while $2, $10 are supposed to be deleted. I cannot just type each column. But you give an idea. I will search for method to print columns with skipping particular ones. Thank you!

Comment: @XiangZhang you can make use of `printf  in for loop` to achieve it.

Comment: @kent, I'm embarrassed to say it was me, and I have no memory of doing it! I'm only knowing it because I saw a `-1` adjustment to my rep and followed it here --- I obviously mis-clicked without even realizing it. Please make any kind of an edit to your answer so that SO will let me undo the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `cut` for that:

```
cut -d$'\t' -f1,3- file
```

`-f1,3-` selects the first field, skips field 2 and then selects fields 3 to end.