# How to delete first three columns in a delimited file

Tags: awk

For example, I have a csv file as follow,

```
12345432|1346283301|5676438284971|13564357342151697 ...
87540258|1356433301|1125438284971|135643643462151697 ...
67323266|1356563471|1823543828471|13564386436651697 ...
```

and hundreds more columns but I want to remove first three columns and save to a new file(if possible same file would be better for me)

This is the result I want.

```
13564357342151697 ...
135643643462151697 ...
13564386436651697 ...
```

I have been looking and trying but I am not able to do it. And below is the code I have.

```
awk -F'|' '{print $1 > "newfile"; sub(/^[^|]+\|/,"")}1' old.csv > new.csv
```

Appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626274/print-all-but-the-first-three-columns

Comment: @Utsav I tried it but all my data are messed up. Is it because of my delimiter is | ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Heng: try:

```
awk -F"|" '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?"":"|")};print ""}'  Input_file
```

**OR**

```
awk -F"|" '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?"\n":"|")};}'  Input_file
```

you could re-direct this command's output into a file as per your need.

**EDIT:**

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR==1{++e;fi="REPORT_A1_"e;} {for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?"\n":"|") > fi}}'   Input_file1  Input_file2  Input_file3
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 ! Cut works too. Do you know is it possible I can remove first three columns for 10 files at once? Do I need to use loop with cut or awk?

Comment: Yes, with awk we could do it, but we need to know your requirement and expected output to help you more. kindly do post the same with details.

Comment: I want to save the output to csv files.  If I do it like what you suggested Input_file1 Input_file2 Input_file3 ............Input_file10, is it means I have to output it to separate file names too? Because all my 10 files have similar names like REPORT_A1_1, REPORT_A1_2, REPORT_A1_3, ........REPORT_A1_10, so I'm wondering if I can have a function to call all these 10 files to be dropped in sequence?

Comment: I commented here. @RavinderSingh13

Comment: please checkout my edit of my answer, you could like it if your question  is solved too :)

Comment: It works too man. You are awesome. Thank you. One more question, after dropping first three columns, is it possible to replace it to original file name and do the same for 10 files at once also? @RavinderSingh13

Comment: I didn't get, you want to put all 10 Input_files output into a single same Input_file ?

Comment: If above is the case then, you could simply put command's output to a temp_input_file and then rename it to Input_file, let me know if this helps.

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. Let me give a example,  For example REPORT_A1_1 has been removed for first three columns right? And I want the data to save back to the same file name, REPORT_A1_1. And I want to do this for all 10 files at one time also, is it possible? Sorry for unclear information and thanks for being patient too. @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cut` :

```
cut -f4- -d'|' old.csv  > new.csv
```

Comment: More efficient than `awk`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you guys know is it possible I can cut first three columns for 10 files at once? Do I need to use loop?

Comment: @HengUnn: Please post sample Input and expected output so that it could be more clear then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The sample input and output are just same as what I posted above. Just I have 10 files which all I have to drop first three columns as well. I'm wondering if there are any ways to do it together for 10 files? So I just need to drop first three columns for 10 files for one time only.

Comment: @HengUnn: just try with my awk above command and then Input_file1  Input_file2  Input_file3 ............Input_file10 and let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

`awk -F '|' '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' oldfile > newfile`

But it will have leading whitespaces so then add the following substitution:

sub(/^[ \t\|]+/,"") --> changed to **sub(/^[ \t\|]+/,"")** (escaped leading '|' from column removal)

`awk -F '|' '{$1=$2=$3="";OFS="|";sub(/^[ \t\|]+/,"") ;print $0}' oldFile > newFile`

Comment: Thanks @SVTAnthony I tried with your code but my output was messed up. All columns are being put into one column.

Comment: use `awk -i inplace -F '|' '{$1=$2=$3=""; gsub(/\s+/,"|");}1' data.txt`

Comment: I just edited the example to fit your needs. What I missed was the Output Field Separator(OFS), I also did some clean up for the leading separators that the removal of the fields caused. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Should set `OFS` _before_ setting `$1=$2=$3=""` -- preferably in BEGIN or commandline `-vOFS='|'` -- and then you only need `sub(/^\|\|\|/,"")` or even simpler `print substr($0,4)`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\| '{print $NF}' file >newfile

13564357342151697 ...
135643643462151697 ...
13564386436651697 ...
```

Comment: Hi!, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and try to provide some explanation why this code. 
Thanks!

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.